# Sets of reals amenable to each L[x]

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

If $A$ is a set of reals such that $A \cap L[x] \in L[x]$ for each real $x$, is there a real $z$ such that $A \cap L[x] \in OD_z^{L[x]}$ for a cone of $x$?

This can be proved under the Axiom of Determinacy using a game of roughly the same complexity as $A$.

Just assuming boldface ${\bf \Delta}^1_2$ determinacy, if $A\cap L[x] \in OD^{L[x]}_z$ for a cone of $x$ then it can be shown that $A$ itself is $OD_z$.
So perhaps one can find a counterexample by finding a homogeneous forcing that does not add reals but adds a set $A$ of reals with $A \cap L[x] \in L[x]$ for each real $x$.

(The assumption of ${\bf \Delta}^1_2$ determinacy is necessary here because starting with $V=L$ it is possible to force a new set $A$ with $A\cap L[x] \in OD^{L[x]}$ for each real $x$ by a homogeneous forcing that does not add reals.)

Comment: It's definitely interesting. Do you have a counterexample showing that a parameter $z$ is required? That is, a set $A$ that is amenable to every $L[x]$, but not necessarily being OD there? 

Comment: I don't know that the parameter $z$ is required, but I put it in there because that's the version of the statement that I know how to prove under AD.

Comment: Acutally I think that taking $A = \{z\}$ where $z$ is a real that is not OD would typically show that a real parameter (e.g., $z$ itself) is required.

Comment: Oh, of course !